# How do I serialize a .Net object to a SOAP string?

Tags: c#, serialization, soap

I am trying to serialize my C# object to a string that I can then pass to a web service using WebClient.  I am successfully converting the object to an XML string, but it's not SOAP.  How do I add a SOAP formatter to this?

Here is my code:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        var mmSync = new MMSync()
        {
            UserName = "myUserName",
            Password = "myPassword"
        };

        DataContractSerializer s = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MMSync));
        var output = string.Empty;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            s.WriteObject(ms, mmSync);
            output = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class MMSync
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is a "SOAP string"? Do you want a ready-to-issue SOAP XML request body? Why? Why not use WCF?

Comment: Because I can't in this project for reasons too long to post here.

Comment: Do you have a WSDL for the SOAP web service?

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest an alternative: Add a **service reference** to your project. This creates a proxy class which *automatically* does all the SOAP encoding/decoding and all the HTTP communication for you.

Details:

- [How to: Add, Update, or Remove a Service Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx)

For more information about the difference between "web references" and "service references" as well as more detailed information, see the following related question:

- [Visual Studio/SOAP - 'Add Service Reference' vs 'Add Web Service Reference'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2192772/87698)

Comment: Believe me, I'd love to do this.  But for reasons too long to post here, this isn't a possibility.

Comment: @Scottie: Ah, ok, I understand. I'll keep my answer here, maybe it will help others with the same question.